# routing bug in an angularjs app with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to get set up an angularJS app with jQuery and I'm using the angular routing system for urls doing something like the following:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/start_page', {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
    controller: 'StartPageController'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/container/:container/thing/:thing', {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
    controller: 'ThingsInContainersController'
  });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/start_page' });

})
```

I can navigate to the start page which has an interface that allows me to select a container_id and a thing_id and then sends me to the route for the container and thing which all works perfectly.  The problem is that if I refresh the container thing page then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#container/1/thing/2]
```

which seems to be a jQuery error from the stack trace.  The trace doesn't mention my code at all.  I tried a few things and it seems that whenever I enter a url with more than one `/` after the `#` I get the error instead of being properly redirected to the start page.  My solution for now was to use `-`s instead of `/`s as a url delimiter which seems to have worked but I suspect there is actually a correct way of doing this and I'm wondering what it is.

My current solution:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/start_page', {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
    controller: 'StartPageController'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/container-:container-thing-:thing', {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
    controller: 'ThingsInContainersController'
  });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/start_page' });

})
```

Comment: Doesn't the href need to be "#/container/1/thing/2"? Also, your element probably needs to use ng-href if you are using handle bars in your url for templating it out.

Comment: There is no reason to create your url in that fashion.  You should be doing this: `/mycontainerthingurl/:containerID/:thingID`

Comment: Can you add the code of the anchor tag?

Comment: @mortalapeman there is no link.  The start_page responds to a form submission with a $location.path() call and that was working fine.  The issue came when I refreshed the page.

Comment: @m.e.conroy why does it matter?

Comment: IMO its just wordy to put what is expected before each variable in the route, when variable names by themselves should be descriptive enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a bug elsewhere in my codebase without realizing it.  I was using the following in code that was for a different part of the app that uses `#` urls to control bootstrap tabs:

```
var activateTab = function() {
  var activeTab = $('[href=' + window.location.hash.replace('/', '') + ']');
  activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
}
```

The problem was that replace by default only replaces the first occurrence of the pattern so it was throwing an error when I had multiple `/`s.

The solution of course:

```
var activateTab = function() {
  var activeTab = $('[href=' + window.location.hash.replace(/\//g, '') + ']');
  activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
}
```